# Python - read and edit individual Excel file rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nltk

I'm loading Excel sheets into Python in order to clean (tokenize, stem et cetera) rows of text. I'm using Pandas to clean each individual line and return a new, cleaned Excel file in the same format as the original. In order for the tokenizer and stemmer to be able to read the Excel file, the Pandas dataframe needs to be in string format.

It more or less works, but the below code splits the text in each row by individual words, resulting in each row only containing one (cleaned) word and not a sentence like the original file. How can I make sure it doesn't split each row of text?

(simplified) code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer 

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')  
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))


excel = pd.read_excel(open('example.xls', 'rb'))
data_to_string = pd.DataFrame.to_string(excel) 

for line in data_to_string:
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(data_to_string) 
    stopped = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words] #removes stop words
    trimmed = [ word for word in stopped if len(word) >= 3 ] #takes out all words of two characters or less. 
    stemmed = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in trimmed] #stems the words
return_to_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(stemmed) #resets back to pandas dataframe
```

I've thought about using this, but it doesn't work:

```
data_to_string = excel.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Edit: Maarten asked if I could upload an image of what my current and desired output would be. The format of the original input file (uncleaned) is on the left. The middle is the desired outcome (stemmed and stop words removed etc.), and the right image is the current output.

[image: Left is original input (csv/excel), middle is desired output, right is current output.]

EDIT: I managed to solve it; the main problem was with the tokenization. First, I had to convert the pandas dataframe to a list of lists (see `strdata` in the code below'), and then tokenize each item in each list. The rest was solved with a simple for loop, appending the cleaned rows back to a list and converting the list back to a pandas dataframe. The `remove_NaN` is there because pandas saw each `None`-type element as a string of alphanumeric characters (namely the word "None") instead of an empty cell, so this string had to be removed. Also, pandas put each tokenized word into a separate column. `mergeddf` is there in order to merge all words back into the same column.

The working code looks like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#load tokenizer, stemmer and stop words
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
stemmer = PorterStemmer() 
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

excel = pd.read_excel(open(inFilePath, 'rb')) #use pandas to read excel file
strdata = excel.values.tolist() #convert values to list of lists (each row becomes a separate list)
tokens = [tokenizer.tokenize(str(i)) for i in strdata] #tokenize words in lists
cleaned_list = []
for m in tokens:
    stopped = [i for i in m if str(i).lower() not in stop_words] #remove stop words
    stemmed = [stemmer.stem(i) for i in stopped] #stem words
    cleaned_list.append(stemmed) #append stemmed words to list

backtodf = pd.DataFrame(cleaned_list) #convert list back to pandas dataframe
remove_NaN = backtodf.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) #remove None (which return as words (str))
mergeddf = remove_NaN.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1) #convert cells to strings, merge columns
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe in CSV, with current and expected outcome. this code will not run either because the `tokenizer` is not defined

Comment: Thanks Maarten, I processed your comments and made some edits.

Comment: I can't copy-paste pictures. please provide it in an easily-imported format, like csv or json

Comment: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10549005-python-as-an-excel-scripting-language

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I managed to solve the problem so I made some edits in my original post. Cheers, and happy new year!